# Where does the provincial budget of Ontario exhibit its spending on the arts, culture, tourism?

Tags: budget, canada

My grandparents read [Here's everything the Doug Ford government cut in its first year in office | National Observer](https://www.nationalobserver.com/2019/06/07/news/heres-everything-doug-ford-government-cut-its-first-year-office), but this exhibits only the differences, not the old and new values. Where can they spot them in [Ontario's budget](http://budget.ontario.ca/2019/contents.html)?

> ### **Arts, culture and tourism**
>
> - Retroactively slashed $5 million from the Ontario Arts Council. This has resulted in the suspension of five programs including National and International Residency Project, Ontario Dances, Publishing Organizations Projects​​​​​​, Theatre Training Projects, Travel Assistance: Ontario Contact/Contact Ontarois
> - Cancelled the Indigenous Culture Fund
> - Dropped grants for the Ontario Music Fund by more than 50 per cent
> - Reduced funding to regional tourism organizations by $17.5 million
> - Announced the termination of the Beer Store contract, jeopardizing 7,000 jobs
> - Cut $9.5 million from Tourism Toronto (25 per cent of funding) and $3.4 million from Ottawa Tourism
> - Celebrate Ontario, which provides funding for music and arts festivals across the province, lost $7 million from its annual budget

Comment: Is the question already answered? If not, what information may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well you won't find it in a partisan document like a government budget statement.

Here is what it says about the Ontario Music Fund

> The government will work with Ontario Creates to modernize the Ontario Music Fund to focus on activities that bring the biggest return to the province, and refocus its investments into emerging talent to create opportunities to achieve success.

It is hard to read language like "refocus" and "modernize", and understand it to be anything else but a "cut".

Similarly the cut in Arts Council funding is a reduction from an expected [$69.9 to 
$64.9 million.](https://twitter.com/skotduck/status/1073300660173590528?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1073310220699533312&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fglobalnews.ca%2Fnews%2F4762100%2Fontario-arts-council-cuts%2F)

Finding such details in the mass of government papers is hard work. They aren't put in the "budget" which is states plans and objectives but doesn't include details of exact spending.

Answer (score 1):

At http://budget.ontario.ca/2019/chapter-3.html#section-6 under the paragraph titled "Tourism, Culture and Sport" it says

```
                                 Actual 2016–17 Actual 2017–18  Interim 2018–19 Plan2019–20
Tourism, Culture and Sport (Total)  1,561           1,590            1,552        1,493.4
```

which hints at a planned cut by ~4% in 2019-20 compared to 2018-19.

The page is filled with empty phrases like "Ontario’s Government for the People" or "people-first approach to ...", I hope it's legit.